# Having trouble building Wix4 setup on GitHub actions

Tags: .net, wix, github-actions, wix4

I have a Wix4 project that builds a setup for my application. The project uses the HeatDirectory task to generate a .wxs file from a folder that contains the files to be installed. The project builds fine on my local machine, but when I try to build it on GitHub actions, it fails with this error:

```
Error: D:\a\PotatoWall\PotatoWall\Setup\Product.wxs(41): error WIX0094: The identifier 'WixComponentGroup:PublishedComponents' could not be found. Ensure you have typed the reference correctly and that all the necessary inputs are provided to the linker. [D:\a\PotatoWall\PotatoWall\Setup\PotatoWallSetup.wixproj]
```

I have tried different options and settings for the task, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue and generate a .wxs file for a Wix4 project on GitHub actions?

Here is the link to my setup project repository:

 https://github.com/poqdavid/PotatoWallSetup/
https://github.com/poqdavid/PotatoWall/actions/workflows/buildsetup.yml

Here are the logs and binlogs from the GitHub action: https://gist.github.com/poqdavid/f8abe40bf0ffd3249c6a0d3d57f52e0a#file-error1-log
https://gist.github.com/poqdavid/f8abe40bf0ffd3249c6a0d3d57f52e0a#file-msbuild1-binlog

Comment: You might collect MSBuild log via `dotnet build -bl` and then see further into the error, https://msbuildlog.com/

Comment: @LexLi  I just generated the log and updated the question I hope that helps